# Why css object should start with prefix o- and component starts with c-?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, oocss, itcss

Is there any reason why in `css naming convention`, some `object` preferably start with prefix `o-` and `component` starts with `c-` ?

I know `o-` will stand for `object` and `c-` stand for `component`, but why don't we just ignore that rules? For example `c-btn`, why we're using `c-`, I thought it was too verbose. Instead using some of that prefix, we can just use `btn`, simple clean and straight to the point.

Please, enlighten me guys. : )

Comment: Since its referrence based on class objects like: they categorized object as o- and component as c-  then they call it that way!

Comment: @moh89 we already categorized those `object` and `component` on separated folder in `css architecture`, but why we still need to naming it like that? My point is those prefix really verbose, am I wrong if I stripped all that prefix on my `components` and `objects`?

Comment: U are not wrong but it might be misfunction sometimes then u could use it for assurance

Comment: @moh89 can you give me an example on how may it be misfunction?

Comment: it might doesnt load ur css objects due to poor reference once u doesnt call it properly.

Answer (score 0):

ITCSS is not OOCSS . 
To aswer your question, with ITCSS you have specific folder location for components, objects...and other family types.

Since it was meant to work with other people, if you write the namespace before the classname everyone can easily recognise where the code and his file is located. If you don't do it, you can have a `.btn`, `.button`, `.circular-button`. What is an object and what is a component?